# Can you redeem event code multiple times on Pokemon Moon/Sun

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I have several Marshadow codes. I know each code is for one machine, but has anyone ever tried to redeem same event multiple code on the same device? Is it per character file or you have to reset?

Comment: I couldn't find anywhere mentioning using multiple of the same event codes on a single device, but since you have several why not give it a go?

Comment: Thank you. It would be a long long trip to get the additional codes (I only got one last time), so I was curious if someone had done this before I drive 100 miles :(. Let me check with a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each event can only be redeemed once per save file, even with multiple codes. By starting a new file, you can use a new code to redeem the event again.

Answer (score -1):

I tried, it doesn't work. The thing is this year's events will give you a different Pokémon depending on if you're on `Moon/Ultra Moon` or `Sun/Ultra Sun`. So if you got yourself `Moon` I suggest you to get `Ultra Sun`, to get all the Legendary Pokémon from the Giveaways